# How to release a stored procedure so an ddl upgrade can be performed

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird, ddl

We have a lot of our business rules stored in stored procedures.  We would like to be able to perform DDL upgrades without having all users kicked out of the db.

Is there some way in Delphi where I can run a query against a stored procedure "Select * from SP_SuperbillSummary(:patientID)" and when I close the query have the sp_superbillsummary go back to being not "in use".

This is just one example.  We have 40+ stored procedures and once Delphi uses them once they become "in use" and stay that way.

DB: Firebird 2.1 latest bug fix version.
Language: Delphi 2007 pro.  w/IB_Objects library for db access.

sample code:

```
procedure TSuperBillList.LoadHeadersByPatient(PatientID: Integer;
  AExcludeSuperBillID: Integer = 0);
{$REGION 'SQLText' }
const SQLText =
  'SELECT *  ' +
    '  FROM  ' +
    '    SP_SUPERBILLHEADERS(:PATIENTID)';
{$ENDREGION}

var
  SB: TSuperBill;
begin
  ClearObjects;
  SetUpQuery(SQLText);
  with q do
  begin
    ParamByName('PATIENTID').AsInteger := PatientID;
    Open;
    try
      while not EOF do
      begin
        {Do some stuff here}
        Next;
      end;
    finally
      q.IB_Transaction.Rollback;
      Close;
    end;
  end;
  SetLoadedAt(Now);
end;
```

Comment: holy typos batman.  I'd edit my initial question if I could find the edit.  "Delphi, Firebird how to tell a stored procedure we're done with it and it should be release so a ddl upgrade can be performed without 'StoredProcedureName is in use.' messsage doesn't come up."

Comment: Oh and I've googled extensively and re-read the book by helen for answers but I can't find anything short of kicking out all the users and forcing them to wait while I work.

Comment: You need to close or unprepare the Firebird statement handle and commit the transaction(s) that used the statement. IIRC there have also been some improvements in this area with Firebird 2.5 and 3.0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  As you an see from my code example.  I do commit/Rollback the transaction and close the query that started the stored procedure.  What else do I need to do?  Free the query?  Its a reusable object TIB_Cursor from IB_Objects.

Comment: I'm just not familiar with Delphi, so I can't help you with that side of things.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010218/how-do-i-get-an-exclusive-lock-on-a-firebird-database-to-perform-schema-changes

Comment: thanks Mark.  hopefully someone else will come along with an idea.